# The alert message is displaying without the login form

Tags: php, codeigniter

In the below codeigniter code i have placed the controller and view part.Now if a inactive tries to log the account it should display in active user along with login form .In my case the message is displaying without login and finally login forms disappear. 
Controller:

```
function index()
    {
        $data['main_content'] = 'login_form';
        $this->load->view('includes/template', $data);      
    }
    function inactive()
    {
    echo"<script>alert('In active user');</script>";
    }

    function validate_credentials()
    {       
        $this->load->model('membership_model');
        $query = $this->membership_model->validate();

        if($query) // if the user's credentials validated...
        {
            $data = array(
                'username' => $this->input->post('username'),
                'is_logged_in' => true
            );
            if($query->num_rows()>0){
             $status = $query->row()->account_status;}
            else {
             $status = ''; }
            if($status == 'active')
            {
               $this->session->set_userdata($data);
               redirect('site1/members_area');
            }
            else //Account In active
            {  $this->inactive();  }
        }
        else // incorrect username or password
        {
            $this->index();
        }
    }
```

view:

```
<?php $this->load->view('includes/header'); ?>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo base_url();?>css/style1.css"  />
<div id="login_form">

    <h1>Login!</h1>
    <?php 
    echo form_open('login/validate_credentials');
    echo form_input('username', 'Username');
    echo form_password('password', 'Password');
    echo form_submit('submit', 'Login');
    echo anchor('login/signup', 'Create Account');
    echo form_close();
    ?>

</div><!-- end login_form-->


<?php $this->load->view('includes/footer'); ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't see where ve you called your view file in `inactive()` in controller??

```
  function inactive()
    {
    echo"<script>alert('In active user');</script>";
     $this->load->view('Your view with login form'); // this part
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the code its working but the msg is not displaying along with the table.

Comment: sorry its login_form i want to display the msg with login_form.but after msg the login_form displays

Comment: Yes it displays both msg and login_form with that code. doesn't it?

Comment: first it displays msg and after the login_form

Comment: And what where u expecting it to do??

Comment: Do you want login form to be popped up with msg?

Comment: Then you ve to use some jquery or javascript popup form in your view file to show login form.

Answer (score 0):

The most obvious (possible) mistake here is that you do not pass your posted data to `$this->membership_model->validate();`. Since you did not post the code to that function I can not be 100% sure, but I am willing to bet that this is the problem. The information is not passed, so the `$query` variable is not properly set, hence the error displays.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try this:

```
function index($inactive_login = FALSE) {
    $data['inactive_login'] = $inactive_login;
    $data['main_content'] = 'login_form';
    $this->load->view('includes/template', $data);
}

function validate_credentials() {       
    $this->load->model('membership_model');
    $query = $this->membership_model->validate();

    if($query) // if the user's credentials validated...
    {
        $data = array(
            'username' => $this->input->post('username'),
            'is_logged_in' => true
        );
        if($query->num_rows()>0){
         $status = $query->row()->account_status;}
        else {
         $status = ''; }
        if($status == 'active')
        {
           $this->session->set_userdata($data);
           redirect('site1/members_area');
        }
        else //Account In active
        { 
            $inactive_login = TRUE;
            $this->index($inactive_login);  
        }
    }
    else // incorrect username or password
    {
        $this->index();
    }
}
```

View:

```
<?php $this->load->view('includes/header'); ?>
<?php 
    if($inactive_login){
        echo "<script>alert('In active user');</script>";
    }
?>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo base_url();?>css/style1.css"  />
<div id="login_form">

<h1>Login!</h1>
<?php 
    echo form_open('login/validate_credentials');
    echo form_input('username', 'Username');
    echo form_password('password', 'Password');
    echo form_submit('submit', 'Login');
    echo anchor('login/signup', 'Create Account');
    echo form_close();
?>
</div><!-- end login_form-->
<?php $this->load->view('includes/footer'); ?>
```